# Visual Studio Code - some features don't work when copy and pasting something large

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I copy and paste something large (such as an SVG markup), the editor becomes very unusable. For example, whenever I copy and paste this SVG markup to my HTML document:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 108 32"><path d="M16.2 12.8h6.4c.9 0 1.7.7 1.7 1.7 0 .9-.7 1.7-1.7 1.7h-6.4c-.9 0-1.7-.7-1.7-1.7s.8-1.7 1.7-1.7zm-.2 3.9h3c.8 0 1.4.6 1.4 1.4 0 .8-.6 1.4-1.4 1.4h-3c-.8 0-1.4-.6-1.4-1.4-.1-.7.6-1.4 1.4-1.4zm-3.7 3.5h6.4c.9 0 1.7.7 1.7 1.7 0 .9-.7 1.7-1.7 1.7h-6.4c-.9 0-1.7-.7-1.7-1.7.1-.9.8-1.7 1.7-1.7zm-4.4 0c1 0 1.7.7 1.7 1.7 0 .9-.7 1.7-1.7 1.7-.9 0-1.7-.7-1.7-1.7 0-.9.8-1.7 1.7-1.7zm19.8.6c.3 2.1 2.4 3 4.8 3 2.7 0 4.6-1.2 4.6-3.4 0-1.5-.9-2.6-2.8-3.1l-2.4-.5c-.6-.1-.8-.4-.8-.7 0-.4.3-.8 1.2-.8 1 0 1.6.6 1.7 1.2l3-.6c-.5-1.8-2.1-2.9-4.7-2.9s-4.4 1.4-4.4 3.4c0 1.6 1.1 2.6 3 3l2.1.4c.7.1 1 .4 1 .7 0 .4-.5.8-1.3.8-.9 0-1.7-.3-1.8-1.2l-3.2.7zm15.1.1c-1.5 0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.5 0-1.5 1-2.5 2.4-2.5 1 0 1.9.6 2.1 1.8l3-.7c-.5-2.5-2.6-4-5.1-4-3 0-5.5 2.2-5.5 5.4s2.5 5.4 5.5 5.4c2.5 0 4.7-1.6 5.2-4l-3-.6c-.3 1.2-1.2 1.7-2.2 1.7zm12.4-7.8c-1.7 0-2.8.9-3.5 2.1v-1.9h-3.2v10.2h3.2v-3.2c0-2.6 1.2-3.8 3.5-3.8h.6l.1-3.2c-.2-.1-.4-.2-.7-.2zm3-4.6c-1.1 0-1.9.8-1.9 1.8s.8 1.8 1.9 1.8c1.1 0 1.9-.8 1.9-1.8s-.8-1.8-1.9-1.8zm1.7 14.9V13.3h-3.2v10.2h3.2v-.1zM73.7 13c-1.6 0-2.8.7-3.6 1.7-.7-1.1-1.9-1.7-3.3-1.7-1.3 0-2.3.5-3 1.2v-.9h-3.2v10.2h3.2v-5c0-1.7.8-2.6 1.9-2.6 1 0 1.7.7 1.7 1.9v5.7h3.2v-5c0-1.7.8-2.6 2-2.6 1 0 1.7.7 1.7 1.9v5.7h3.2v-6.4c.1-2.5-1.6-4.1-3.8-4.1zm10.8 0c-1.3 0-2.4.4-3.2 1.1V8.9h-3.2v14.6h3.2v-.8c.8.7 1.8 1.1 3.2 1.1 2.7 0 5-2.2 5-5.4-.1-3.2-2.3-5.4-5-5.4zm-.7 8c-1.3 0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.6 0-1.6 1.2-2.6 2.5-2.6 1.4 0 2.4 1.1 2.4 2.6s-1 2.6-2.4 2.6zm17.4-7.7H98v.8c-.8-.7-1.8-1.1-3.2-1.1-2.7 0-5 2.2-5 5.4s2.3 5.4 5 5.4c1.3 0 2.4-.4 3.2-1.1v.8h3.2V13.3zM95.5 21c-1.4 0-2.4-1.1-2.4-2.6 0-1.6 1-2.6 2.4-2.6 1.3 0 2.5 1.1 2.5 2.6S96.8 21 95.5 21z"/></svg>
```

Here's a list of problems that happens to the editor after that:

- Saving a file becomes slow
- Basic keyboard shortcuts such as copy and pasting (Ctrl + C / Ctrl + V) no longer work
- Whenever you hover over a tag, the IntelliSense is stuck on *Loading...*
- The editor becomes slow and choppy

In terms of my computer specs, I do have a gaming computer where I can comfortably play most modern games, so I don't think it's the computer itself that is the problem. Has this problem also occured to anyone else by any chance? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Something large?What do you mean?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but it's not the amount of characters. That's a tiny bit of code in any context.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds strange.

The SVG snippet you provided is not very "large". I already pasted thousands of lines in VS Code and everything still worked. Eventually, when the file is above 100k lines, syntax highlighting might become slow. But even in this case, VS Code pops up a message to say it deactivated some features to keep working.

Here's what I'd suggest:

1. **Check your extensions performance**. I described how to do so in a blog post: https://www.nicoespeon.com/en/2019/11/fix-vscode-extension-performance-issue/#how-to-measure-the-performance-of-a-vs-code-extension. Maybe there's a culprit making your editor slow.
2. Check your settings, searching for "large file optimization". Here's how mines look like:

[image: My VS Code settings]

3. If you don't find an extension causing the editor to be slow, I'd **try to reinstall VS Code** (in an attempt to fix the problem without really understanding what's going on )